# RCP register the buttons...how?

Tags: java, button, eclipse-rcp

I have a problems with creating of primitive buttons...

I created the button in preWindowOpen() method:

```
   JButton btn1 = new JButton("Submit");
```

But how can i register it in plugin.xml? Add to my app and make it visible i mean

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Registering a button to do what?

Why are you using a JButton?  That's a Swing construct and Eclipse apps use SWT (generally).

Comment: Thx for answer. I just wanna add to my form a buttons... but all tutorials which i seen didn't help me.
About registering: i should to create the button incode with 'new' operator, after i should to add it somehow to the form with plugin.xml, right? I called it registering)
I using a jbutton cause i saw few examples with it :D
   Explain to me how to add a buttons to the form please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to understand the structure of RCP. I highly recommend you the tutorial from vogella - [Eclipe 4 RCP](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html). It's a lot to read, but you will get the basics of Eclipse RCP and it is really user friendly written.